# exponential of real(16) in fortran

Tags: fortran, infinity

The largest number that is not an infinity in the model of the type of `real(16)` is 10^4932. I have the `exp(10000)` in Fortran 90 code that is  8.806818225×10^4342 calculated by simple calculator. I use this simple code:

```
real(16) :: a
...
a = exp(10000)
...
```

But it returns infinity. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, who knows what is `real(16)`, the kind numbers are not portable and may mean anything.

But let's say you want to use real of kind 16 whatever it actually is. Then you have to put real of kind 16 into the exp function

```
  a = exp(10000._16)
```

In Fortran expressions never care about their surroundings. `exp(10000)` is evaluated independently and in the same way in all contexts. You put a default integer there and you got the answer in default real. The answer is too big for default real.

I **strongly** suggest using some proper way to defind your kinds than just 16.

```
use iso_fortran_env
integer, parameter :: rp = real128
real(rp) :: a

a = exp(10000._rp)
```

is one of the possible ways.

Comment: Thanks, it works. how about I have variable, like for example `real(8)::x` of order of magnitude 10000  instead of number 10000?

Comment: Try real64 instead of real128

Comment: Hi, what is the largest possible `rp`? I tried `rp = real256`, but it is not acceptable.

Comment: 128 and only in some compilers. It is also quite slow, 64 is much faster and most people use it.

Comment: So, this, `rp = real128`, is the bound of large number. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, in practice it is.

Comment: What programming language do you suggest to deal with larger numbers? For example exp(1000000).

Comment: You can use some library for large numbers in many languages including Fortran.

Comment: can you introduce some of these libraries in fortran which can help me in this special case? I heard these libraries for the first time.